# Privillage Module Search on Username (PHP,JQuery,Javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, search

I'm doing a module where a user suppose to assign into a specific group. With a bunch of list of users, I was thinking of if I'm doing checkboxes it might be crazy of scrolling. Unless I do a search sorting method. Somehow don't know which searching method is more reliable.

Any suggestions and ideas on it ? Much appreciate for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the users potentially belong to more than one group?

If so, try a dynamic combo-box(`<select multiple>`), which is populated with the groups.  Useful for setting groups for the users or getting a list of users from multiple groups.

If not, just use a regular old drop-down selection (`<select>`) populated with the groups for assigning them.  Might still want a combobox for searching though, since you can select multiple groups at once.

Something like:

```
<?php
$groups = //array of group names pulled from somewhere, such as an array pulled from MySQL
echo '<select name="groups[]" multiple>';
foreach($groups as $group)
{
    echo '<option value="' . $group['id'] . '">' . $group['name'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Unless I'm not getting what you're asking.

Comment: Thx for the quick response, I somehow discussed with friends and implemented with full ajax. ^^